# C++ error: expected unqualified error-id before '(' token

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, struct

Im wondering what I've done wrong in my code that is throwing the error.
(Note that due to external restrictions the use of -> is not allowed and brackets[] are not allowed anywhere except during array declaration)

Here are my two structs:

```
struct RentalCar
{
    char make[10];
    char model[10];
    int year;
    float price;
    bool available;
};

struct Agency
{
    char name[10];
    int zipcode;
    RentalCar inventory[5];
    RentalCar* myCar = inventory;
};
```

Later in my code I have the following

```
Agency myAgencies[3];
Agency* myPointer = myAgencies;
```

I later try to reference the following when I get my error

```
inFile>>(*myPointer).(*myCar).make;
```

Due to external conditions, I'm not allowed to use the following fix:

```
inFile>>(*myPointer).inventory[0].make;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Raw N I only come to stack overflow if google cannot help me. I've taken 3 years of C++ so reading up any further on syntax isn't going to help my knowledge on the language. I asked this question separately because it is on how to fix a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Your pointer dereferencing syntax isn't quite right. Perhaps the easiest way to fix this is by rewriting the

```
(*myPointer).(*myCar).make
```

using the arrow operator:

```
myPointer->myCar->make
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention in the question that (also due to external restrictions) the use of -> is not allowed. (I'll be sure to edit that in my question!)

Comment: @GunnerStone You are not allowed to use a fundamental, built in operator?

Comment: @NathanOliver No, the use of it isnt allowed for my case (sadly) or I wouldnt be having this issue :( This answer would work (in the real world) just not with my restriction.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use `->` then what what you can use is drop using the pointers and use the arrays themselves.

```
inFile>>(*myPointer).(*myCar).make;
```

Becomes

```
inFile >> myAgencies[0].inventory[0].make;
```

Comment: I know you are going to be triggered, with your comment on the other post... But brackets are restricted and not allowed to be used anywhere except for array declaration... #I'm very sad

Comment: @GunnerStone If you keep changing the requirements no one is going to want to help you.  As is I would leave wherever you are being taught and go somewhere else.  They are only doing you a disservice.